# How to express .filter() function recursively in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Here is a mapping function I was exercising on;

```
var list = [1,2,3,4,5];

function isOdd(v) {
    return v % 2 == 1;
}

function exclude(arr, fn) {
    var myList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (fn(arr[i])) {
            myList.push(arr[i]);
        }
    };
    return myList;
}
```

I want to replace for loop with a recursive solution but it doesn't produce a proper array since I started a new list in each function call at line 2. How can I solve it with a recursion? Here is the closest I got;

```
function exclude(arr, fn) {
    let myList = [];
    if (arr.length = 1) {
        if (fn(arr[0])) {
            return myList.push(arr[0]);
        }
    } else {
        return myList.push(exclude(arr.slice(1), fn));
    }
}

console.log(exclude(list, isOdd));
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `list.filter(isOdd)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one solution. I have changed a bit your implementation.

```js
function exclude(arr, fn, output) {
  output || (output = []);
  
  if(!arr.length) { 
    return output;
  }
  
  if (fn(arr[0])) {
    output.push(arr[0]);
  }

  return exclude(arr.slice(1), fn, output);
}

console.log(exclude([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], function(i) { return i % 2; }));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (arr.length = 1) {
```

This assigns 1 to `arr.length`, effectively trimming the array if there are more than 1 items in it.  You probably meant `arr.length ===`.

Secondly, the `Array#push` method returns the new length of the array, not the array itself, so where you have:

```
return myList.push(arr[0]);
```

You probably want:

```
myList.push(arr[0]);
return myList;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the original array and make copy of the original array on each recursive call, here could be an ugly solution

```
function exclude(arr, fn, result, index) {
    if (!result) {
        result = [];
        index = -1;
    }
    index++;
    if (index < arr.length && fn(arr[inndex]))
        result.push(arr[index]);
    if (index === arr.length)
        return result;
    return exclude(arr, fn, result, index);
}

console.log(exclude([1,2,3,4], function(i){return i%2===0;})); // prints "2,4"
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your example doesn't really fit with recursion. It is much more readable and less prone to errors to use the `for` loop here. Recursion can easily mess things up in JS because of contexts and scopes. If you really want to do it as a test case, i recommend you not to transform the array, it will be slow and not of much use. Anyway at the end, you will end with same behaviour as a `for` loop, but less efficient. here is an example:

```js
var list = [1,2,3,4,5];

function isOdd(v) {
    return v % 2 == 1;
}

function exclude(arr, fn, optionalIndex) {
    var myList = [];
    if(!optionalIndex){
        optionalIndex = 0;
    }
    if(optionalIndex < arr.length){
        if(fn(arr[optionalIndex])){
            myList.push(arr[optionalIndex]);
        }
        myList = myList.concat(exclude(arr, fn, optionalIndex + 1));
    }
    return myList;
}

console.log(exclude(list, isOdd));
```

It actually would be more interesting for you to try to do it with a real recursion case, for example, using your version with `for` loop to filter this array with sub-arrays in it:

var list = [1, 2, 3, [0, 1, 2, [0, 10, 20, 30], 4], 5, [1 ,2 ,3]];

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun of it, one line solution:

```
function exclude(a, fn, c) {
  return (c = c || (c !== 0 ? a.length - 1 : c)) >= a.splice(c, fn(a[c]) ? 0:1)*0 ? exclude(a, fn, c - 1) : a;
}
```

Snippet:

```js
var list = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

function isOdd(v) {
    return v % 2 != 0;
}

function exclude(a, fn, c) {
  return (c = c || (c !== 0 ? a.length - 1 : c)) >= a.splice(c, fn(a[c]) ? 0:1)*0 ? exclude(a, fn, c - 1) : a;
}

console.log(exclude(list, isOdd));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript doesn't have tail call elimination a recursive solution over a large array will blow your stack. However a functional and recursive approach to the problem would look something like this:

```
function filter(arr, fn) {
    var stopAt = arr.length;
    function helper (index, acc) {
        return index === stopAt ? 
               acc : 
               helper(index+1, fn(arr[index]) ?
                               acc.concat([arr[index]]) :
                               acc) ;
    }
    return helper(0, []);
}
```

Of course this should never be production code. Having a functional interface while allowing for mutating internal structures is probably the best approach. If you were to look at the source for the functional library [Rambda](https://github.com/ramda/ramda) you see that they do mutate internal state.